# Is there any way to get my custom email headers in bounce back email header section instead of in message body using c#

Tags: c#, email, email-headers, email-bounces

I'm sending emails with few custom headers in emails using SmtpClient (C#).

If any email bounce back due to wrong recipient email id, then I need to track those bounce back emails by reading those email using pop3 in c#.

**Is there any way to do some sort of settings/configuration to get these custom email headers in bounce back email headers?** Currently I'm getting these headers as part of bounce back email message body.

Thanks in advance,
Shiv Kumar

Comment: is there any solution for this problem?